# Azure: Traffic routing to deployment slots not working

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have a problem with routing production traffic automatically to deployment slots.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots?tabs=portal#route-production-traffic-automatically

For one app service we use, when we activate this no matter which percentage "x-ms-routing-name" is always set to "self" so it never reaches the deployment slot we configured for traffic routing (I removed cookies after every try).

Interestingly when we created an entirely new app service for testing and deployed exactly the same code there it worked without problems there (x-ms-routing-name changed between self and the slot name according to the configured percentage).

But I could not find any major configuration changes between both app services.

Is there anything to consider regarding the used app service to make sure that the traffic routing works?

Best regards

Comment: In the app service, click on the "Deployment slots" blade.
In the "Deployment slots" blade, make sure that the "Traffic routing" checkbox is checked for the slot that you want to route traffic to.
[Image](https://i.imgur.com/pxnV7Zk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your issue description, it seems like you are having trouble with routing production traffic automatically to deployment slots in one of your Azure App Services ( exactly the same code).

It seems like the x-ms-routing-name header is always set to "self" instead of the deployment slot name, even when you have configured the traffic routing percentage.
To isolate the issue, you may check to ensure that traffic routing works as expected:

1. Check if there are any custom headers or cookies being set in your problematic webapp that might be interfering with the x-ms-routing-name header. You may try removing any custom headers or cookies and see if that resolves the issue.
2. Doublecheck that the deployment slot is configured correctly for traffic routing. From Azure Portal >>"Deployment slots" >> and verifying that the "Traffic %", "Slot setting", and "Slot name" fields are set correctly.

*(As mentioned by Naveen Sharma in the comment (above) with a screenshot)*

Just to highlight, as mentioned in the [Azure document](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots?tabs=portal#route-production-traffic-automatically):

> After a client is automatically routed to a specific slot, it's
> "pinned" to that slot for one hour or until the cookies are deleted.
> On the client browser, you can see which slot your session is pinned
> to by looking at the x-ms-routing-name cookie in your HTTP headers. A
> request that's routed to the "staging" slot has the cookie
> x-ms-routing-name=staging. A request that's routed to the production slot has the cookie x-ms-routing-name=self.